# AngularJS routing's not showing hyphens for spaces in between words

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I configured my routes as expected (of course, inside my app.js file). I made it with ui-router instead of our native "ngRoute". All of them look like the following:

```
    .state('segment', {
        url: "/:segmentId",
        data: { segmentId: "1" },
        ncyBreadcrumb: { skip: true },
        templateUrl: "resources/views/segment.html",
        controller: 'SegmentCtrl'
    })
```

As you can see, it has its own controller and view (templateUrl). And a designated url as well. This "segmentId" is a variable that consumes data from a JSON file. Inside that file, it takes the name of a determined key to use its value. This value will be my URL name.

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "This is my url",
},
```

But here's the catch:

When I have spaces in between words it should look like this: www.example.com/this-is-my-url/

But it looks like this:

www.example.com/thisaisamyaurl/

Don't have the foggiest idea of what's happening here.

Comment: Can you show us the code where it grabs the url from the json file and passes it in as the `segmentId` value?  It seems like you could likely do a `name.replace(/\s/g, '-');` to replace the spaces with dashes

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my slugify function. It wasn't well declared.

```
            // remove accents, swap Ã± for n, etc
            var from = "Ã£Ã Ã¡Ã¤Ã¢áº½Ã¨Ã©Ã«ÃªÃ¬Ã­Ã¯Ã®ÃµÃ²Ã³Ã¶Ã´Ã¹ÃºÃ¼Ã»Ã±Ã§Â·/_,:;";
            var to   = "aaaaaeeeeeiiiiooooouuuunc------";
            for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
                str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
            }
```

Now it is:

```
            // remove accents, swap ñ for n, etc
            var from = "ãàáäâẽèéëêìíïîõòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
            var to   = "aaaaaeeeeeiiiiooooouuuunc------";
            for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
                str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
            }
```

And it works.